# Применение рекурсии для вывода древовидной структуры

Tags: рекурсия, php, mysql

Доброго всем времени суток господа

```
// таблица для вывода
+----+------+--------+
| id | name | parent |
+----+------+--------+
| 1  | ***  | 0      |
| 2  | ***  | 1      |
| 3  | ***  | 1      |
| 4  | ***  | 2      |
| 5  | ***  | 4      |
| 6  | ***  | 0      |
| 7  | ***  | 8      |
| 8  | ***  | 0      |
+----+------+--------+
```

Собственно хочу вывести значения таблицы, главных элементов, и дочерних у них

```
// mysql запрос1 где parent=0
// выводим в цикле1
    // внутри цикла1 делаем запрос2 где parent=(id от запроса1)
    // выводим в цикле2
        // внутри цикла2 делаем запрос3 где parent=(id от запроса2)
        // выводим в цикле3
        // конец цикла 3        
    // конец цикла 2    
// конец цикла 1
```

Ест-но дело попахивает внедрением рекурсии, но к сожалению сам не смог реализовать рекурсию по примерам из интернета. Может кто помочь?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я бы не делал рекурсивный запрос к базе данных, если данные умещаются в память.

Если завести древовидную структуру в памяти, вывод её будет очевиден. Структура получается такая (всё на псевдокоде)

```
item:
    id
    name
    children: array of item
```

При приходе очередного элемента делаем так:

```
item = new { id, name, children = empty array }
allitems[id] = item
allitems[parent].children.append(item)
```

Теперь выводить легко:

```
OutputItemRec(item)
{
    OutputItem(item);
    for each (child in item.children)
        OutputItemRec(child)
}
```

---

Если данные и правда не помещаются в память, можно сделать так:

```
OutputItemRec(itemid)
{
    name = (SELECT name FROM T WHERE id = itemid)
    Output(name)
    chilrenids = (SELECT id FROM T WHERE parent = itemid)
    for each (childid in chilrenids)
        OutputItemRec(childid)
}
```

Comment: А если объем данных большой?

Comment: Если данные не влазят в память, без многочисленных запросов не обойтись, конечно. А у вас и правда данные в память не помещаются?

Comment: если скажу что да - мне никто не поверит. спасибо за ответ

Comment: Большой - в вашем понимании это сколько? Я, например, не стесняюсь обрабатывать в памяти объёмы в десятки тысяч записей...

Comment: На нормальном хостинге так и есть, но вот на плохом хостинге не всегда

Comment: @mixalef: добавил вариант для огромного объёма данных.