# Структура БД для блога

Tags: php, mysql

Пишу блог, сейчас пишу стену, интересует вот такой вопрос. Какая должна быть структура БД для хранения сообщений стены, при регистрации создавать таблицу, где будут хранится сообщения, для каждого пользователя?

**Обновление**
Спасибо всем

Comment: Структура должна быть такая, какая Вам нужна. А это зависит от функциональности Вашего блога и извращенности Вашей фантазии(в отношении функционала блога). Чтобы не получать *умных* ответов напишите пожалуйста реальную проблему с которой Вы сталкиваетесь при разработке структуры бд.

Comment: я пока не создал таблицу для сообщений, немного раньше я создавал одну таблицу где хранились все сообщения, а я по логину их выбирал и выводил уже, но в таком случае в одной таблице будет очень много записей, а если создавать под каждого пользователя таблицу, то таблиц очень много будет. Я только учусь, и вот хочу узнать как сделать что бы было максимально удобно и быстро когда будет очень много пользователей.

Comment: @O.Vykhor, как выше говорил Alex, всё зависит от того какими функциональными возможностями вы хотите наградить свой блог, обычный запрос на 3-4 столбца с данными в виде Int и варчар, с добавленными индексами, занимает не более 2х секунд в выборке 500000 записей(у меня). Вероятно у вас в блоге будет постраничная навигация, вероятно, вы захотите использовать Ajax. Так что всё зависит от планируемой масштабируемости и нагрузки. Но минимальную, и простую начальную структуру, я привел в ответе

Answer (score 2):

В общих чертах:

```
#users
id | login | password | screen_name

#posts
id | alias | author_id | date_posted

#posts_content
post_id | language_id | title | post_body

#comments
id | post_id | author_id | text | date_posted | parent_comment_id
```

С таблицей пользователей, думаю, все понятно (`screen_name` - отоброжаемое имя пользователя).

Пользователи могут создавать посты. Посты хранятся в таблице `posts`, где `author_id` - идентификатор пользователя, создавшего пост, ссылается на запись из таблицы `users`.
Содержание постов (т.е., заголовки, текст на разных языках; возможно и метаданные) хранится в таблице `posts_content`. В принципе, эти данные можно хранить в одной таблице, т.е. совместить `posts` и `posts_content` (например, если планируется, что посты будут только на одном языке, без переводов).
Комментарии хранятся в таблице `comments`, где `post_id`- идентификатор записи из таблицы `posts`, `author_id` - идентифиатор записи из таблицы `users`, `parent_comment_id` - идентификатор "родительского комментария" (используется, если необходимо отобразить комментарий, как ответ, на другой комментарий).

Чуть подробнее по поводу `comments.parent_id`: выборка и вывод иерархической структуры комментариев может оказаться не такой тривиальной задачей.
Если возьметесь ее реализовывать, советую ознакомиться с: 
[Применение рекурсии для вывода древовидной структуры](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/216730/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D1%8B)
и
http://www.getinfo.ru/article610.html.

Создавать таблицу под каждого пользователя - не самая лучшая идея, как по мне. Большое колличество записей в таблице не должно Вас пугать, но при создании таблицы позаботьтесь о том, чтобы расставить индексы: как минимум индексируйте `post_id` и `author_id`.

Также советую почитать документацию почти по любому фреймворку. Там почти везде в качестве вступительного упражнения идет создание блога (как "Hello World" в языках программирования), структура данных, как правило, в общих чертах тоже обсуждется.

Answer (score 1):

Ну, вероятно, надо минимум 2 таблицы: `Пользователи(user_id, nick, password)` и `Сообщения(id, title, text, id_blog(id этой же таблицы), user_id, date)` ну а дальше, разными запросами можно выбрать разное. К примеру для начала делаем выборку всех `Id` в которых не установлено `Id_blog`, а значит это основа того или иного блога, и выводим блоги, а дальше, при открытии каждого конкретного ищем по `id` блога, записи у которых `id_blog` равно этому значению это и будут сообщения этого блога.

Comment: Я что то подобное делал уже, но когда там наберется очень много записей грузиться очень долго будет же

Answer (score 0):

Это сложный вопрос на который есть несколько вопросов

> Использование mysql (реалиционной б.д.) и простой структуры как в
>   ответе Igor Karpenko которая в принципе покроет ваш функционал.

Плюсы:

- целостность данных

Минусы:

- при разростание и расширение функционала проэкта, вероятны сложности
  внедрения нового

> Не реалиционные база данных. Вы просто создаёте колекцию ложите в
>       неё и получаете такими же какими они были при сохранение.

Плюсы:

- Нет структуры
- Лёгкое внедрение нового функционала(хранение для него данных)

Минусы:

- Нет структуры (приходиться в коде контролировать целостность данных)

> И последние это комбенирование двух архитектур реалиционной и не
>   реалиционной баз данных. Т.е. использовать mysql там где нужна
>   структура и целостность данных, а noSql (mongoDB к примеру) там где
>   целостность данных не важна, и есть обработка этих данных и приведение
>   их к определёной структуры для хранения в реалиционной б.д. (на пример
>   это всякие деревья, статьи и т.д.)